# Catalina: Instruments with Full Disk Access

Tags: permission, catalina, preferences, instruments

I am trying to use `Instruments` on my laptop, but it seems that **after updating to Catalina**, it cannot access my `Documents` folder:

[image: instruments]

I have given access to the application, **Full Disk Access**, but it does not work (I even shut down the laptop and restarted it, and also checked for errors with `Disk Utility`).

[image: preferences]

Am I missing something?

Comment: What version of Xcode do you have?

Comment: @Harcker I am running Xcode Version 11.1 (11A1027)

Comment: Try also: from Xcode ->Services ->Toggle Instrument Recording. Doing that added also Xcode to File And Folders in Privacy.

Comment: @Yoan adding Xcode did the trick! If you turn the comment in an answer I'll mark it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Xcode you may start using Instruments with Xcode -> Services -> Toggle Instruments Recording.

This will trigger a chain of settings events inside OSX. The result can be verified by looking to File and Folders in Privacy tab (Xcode will be added also there).